# Calculation of Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from 4th page of [**A mean curvature type flow in space forms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnu081), I try to calculate the red line, but I got a different result.
$$
\mathcal L_V d\rho^2 = d(\mathcal L _V \rho^2)=d(\phi(\rho)\partial_\rho(\rho^2))
=d(2\rho \phi(\rho))=2\rho \phi' d\rho+2\phi d\rho
$$
why the $2\phi d\rho$ vanish ?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can prove the red line.
$$\mathcal L_V(d\rho \otimes d\rho) = \mathcal L_V(d\rho) \otimes d\rho + d\rho\otimes \mathcal L_V(d\rho)  $$
Since $V=\phi \frac \partial {\partial \rho}$ exploiting the commutativity of $\mathcal{L}$ and $d$ we have  that $\mathcal{L}_V(d\rho)=d \mathcal{L}_V(\rho)=d(V(\rho))=d\phi=\frac \partial {\partial \rho}\phi \ d\rho.$
Thus  $$\mathcal L_V(d\rho \otimes d\rho) = \mathcal L_V(d\rho) \otimes d\rho + d\rho\otimes \mathcal L_V(d\rho) = 2 \frac \partial {\partial \rho}\phi \ d\rho\otimes d\rho  $$

Comment: Thanks , I confuse $d(\rho^2)$ and $d\rho \otimes d\rho$